# Current electricity: the drift velocity

Tags: electromagnetism

In physics it is told that in conductor electrons moves with average velocity when electric field is applied and velocity Is independent of time yet electrons are accelerated. How is it possible?

Comment: This question could be edited and elaborated on better. It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: In the drift regime electrons are colliding with the lattice and the resulting energy loss keeps the average velocity constant.

Comment: In English, only use a capital letter for the first word of each sentence and [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun).

Comment: @DanielSank: I knew it! We need to hire an English major! :-). Did your experiment work, by the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrons are accelerated for very small time
(the relaxation time) ,then they collide with other electrons in metal.
The relaxation time is nearly same and constant for each such collision.
During this time they gain some velocity,(called drift velocity),
which is almost same for each such collision of electrons.
This gives us a nearly constant overall drift velocity.

Comment: why average velocity is independent of time although acceleration takes place

Comment: because it is accelerated for a small time {\10^-3} seconds. average velocity during that small time is taken which is nearly same for all accelerations.after each collision electron has to again ready itself for acceleration. the speed and momentum that it had gained in motion towards electric field is almost reversed after each collision.

Comment: relaxation time and time is different or same in drift velocity

Comment: relaxation time comes in discussion in drift velocity. time is something which flows non stop and has no major effect on drift velocity in ideal case

Comment: as I have earlier said relaxation time is time between two consecutive collision, which is almost constant for a given resistor.

Comment: it is told in book that velocity does not depend upon time does it also mean that it does not depend upon relaxation time

Comment: drift velocity Vd = eEt/m , where e is charge on electron, E is applied electric field, t is relaxation time and m is mass of electron. so, Vd depends on relaxation time. but relaxation time (RT) itself is constant (at same temperature) for given resistor. So, you may say it is dependent on RT but independent of time.

Comment: what you didn't understand?

Comment: in ncert physics +2 book part-1 page no.98 2nd paragraph 1st line it is told that this last result is surprising.it tells us that the electrons move with average velocity which is independent of time although electrons is accelerating....        please describe this whole situation

Comment: i explained above the same.

Comment: the increase in velocity is for very short time(RT). during this time average velocity of electrons is taken. After RT they collide with next electron and again start from 0 to that average velocity.

Comment: u r saying exactly right bt i have problem with time and relaxation time as it told that it does not depend on time bt it depends on relaxation time ........ how? time and relaxation time is different in this

Comment: ????????????????????????

Comment: if drift velocity would have depend on time , than as time would pass either electrons will increase. As a result of which current would eventually increase. But we find that, till time resistance is constant, current is constant. relaxation time is constant time b/w collisions. Once this RT is calculated we now do not need to depend on time. As time would pass their would be no change in current.  NCERT their meant this, that velocity will no more change with passage of time.RT is like a characteristic for a given conductor and not merely time of clock.

Comment: thnks alot u helped me alot